# How to open Public IPv6 IP on browser without DNS

Tags: browser, dns, ipv6

I am trying to open IPv6 on browser .

For localhost , i tried :

```
http://::1
```

--> does not work

I try :

```
http://[::1]
```

--> it works

Howerver , i try to open a public IP (google.com IP6  , see `$ host google.com` output)  :
[image]

```
http://2a00:1450:4006:803::200e
```

i try also :

```
http://[2a00:1450:4006:803::200e]
```

--> All attempts make failure .

### Without altering `/etc/hosts` configuration file, how can we open this version of IPs ?

Comment: Most webserver need the hostname in the request because there can be multiple websites on one address. Connecting with only the address won't give the server enough information. That's the same for both IPv4 and IPv6

Comment: @SanderSteffann That is not true, the ip just points to the root account of the server, if you have multiple accounts on one server you can access these accounts by `ip/home/accountname`.

Comment: @BasvanStein: that may work on some servers, but most servers aren't configured like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make firefox use ipv6 enter -> `about:config` in the adress-bar. In the field beside `-> Filter:` enter ipv6. There is an option named  `network.dns.disable.IPv6`. Doubleclick on it so it value turns to false and firefox will check about IPv6 now.

You should use the bracket notation like you did

```
http://[2a00:1450:4006:803::200e]/
```

Comment: Of course, that assumes the Internet connection and the ISP are capable of IPv6.

Comment: Currently this works with default settings in `about:config`, however Google will respond with a 404 page, because the `Host` header of the `GET` request sent by Firefox will contain the IPv6 address, whereas Google HTTP server expects `www.google.com` there.